# Прощание "пока"

Tags: этимология

Есть фамильярное прощание "пока". А откуда оно взялось? Пока — что?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что ПОКА - это слово, которое осталось от фразы "Мы ещё увидимся, а пока до свидания". Его очень удобно произносить, оно короткое, лёгкое.

Answer (score 1):

На эту тему можно много фантазировать, например: "Я пока здесь, но прощаюсь с Вами", "Пока я не ушел, желаю Вам всего наилучшего". Думаю, можно провести аукцион: кто больше придумает подобных фраз?

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что когда мы говорим пока, подразумеваем, что на данный момент, на сегодня, в данных условиях и обстоятельствах.
Например: - пока я не готова к нашей встрече. 
А при прощании - пока, пока, однозначно что ещё увидимся, но сейчас необходимо проститься, но рада буду встрече.
Опять же, это моя интерпритация и ощущение этого прощания.

Answer (score -1):

ПОКА — ПОКидАю
Как короткий вариант частного (не официального) прощания в обиходе. 
 
Принадлежит группе "сложных" базовых, коренных слов русского языка, т. е. как:

- разговорное сокращение известного, но литературного слова;
- аббревиатура, составленная из слов, входящих в какое то понятие, предложение.

Как один из многочисленных и ярких примеров:
ВИНО — ВИноградный Напиток Отстоявшийся;
ВОКЗАЛ — ВОКальный ЗАЛ (как сооружение на железной дороге, в котором отдыхала царская семья, путешествовавшая по первой железной дороге в России) и многие другие, казалось бы, "странно возникшие" слова.

Comment: Народная этимология, даже настолько причудливая, здесь не в почёте.